# How can one make a periodic Markov chain aperiodic with the smallest change in the main structure of the chain?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

Or, how can one "deform" a stochastic, irreducible, *periodic* matrix into a stochastic, irreducible, *aperiodic* matrix with the smallest change?

If there are several possible procedures, then please mention them. If the procedure is complex, then please provide sufficient explanation or link of blogs/books etc. I want to analyze them and check which makes the smallest change in the original graph/chain/matrix.

Comment: A standard trick to make a Markov chain aperiodic is to take a linear combination between your markov matrix and the identity matrix.  Sometimes the modified chain is called a "lazy random walk".

Comment: To be slightly more specific, @Omnomnomnom 's suggestion is to take a *convex* combination with the identity matrix, and if you want to change the original chain as little as possible then you can assign an arbitrarily small weight to the identity matrix part.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Still looking for more.

Comment: Another option is to connect all states to some particular state, and then join that state to itself. That state could be one of the existing states or you could augment the chain with it.

Comment: "Smallest" in what norm?

Comment: Thanks for your second suggestion, I think adding a new node and connect it with every node and itself is better because the original graph is same and as we are connecting the node with every node, no bias happens. But here the added node will have some value on the steady-state vector. As the added node is not in the real graph, that means the value of the added node is coming from other nodes. Now how can I distribute the added node's value to other nodes so that no bias happens?  If you have the answer then, please explain or provide the link of blog/books/papers. @Ian

Comment: If you want to keep the same steady state then the identity matrix idea is ideal.

Comment: Thanks, sir. I think arbitrarily small weight in the identity matrix will make the process longer to converge in a steady state. So there is a tradeoff between keeping the original structure and convergence time. Am I right? please confirm me. @Ian

Comment: Technically yes, but if you just want to get the steady state by Monte Carlo then you can just use local averages (where the length of the average is the period of the chain) rather than passing through a modified chain in the first place.

Comment: Sir, currently what I am doing is, adding an identity matrix of which is all diagonal value is 0.1, Can you give me any better way to choose the constant? @Ian

Comment: You don't just add, you have to scale down the original matrix proportionally to keep the matrix stochastic. The actual value doesn't matter that much, it just changes the convergence rate. I think generically the fastest convergence rate for a periodic chain will be obtained with a 0.5 probability to not move.